# SchemaCrawler 16.12 version command line not creating my htmlx output

Tags: command-line, graphviz, schemacrawler

I am using the latest version of `schemacrawler (16.1.2)` to generate SVG diagrams embedded in HTML output. However it is not creating the diagrams but only printing the table information in text form. If I use an older version of `schemacrawler`, it works fine. I have Graphviz installed on my machine. What am I doing wrong that is not outputting the diagram?

For Version 16.1.2 this version of the command line I use is not working

> source schemacrawler.sh --server=postgresql --host=hostname --database=db_name --user=username --password=password_name --info-level=standard --schemas=schema_name --command=schema --outputformat=htmlx --log-level=CONFIG > schemaGraph.html

For Version 14.17, this version of the command works fine for me

> source schemacrawler.sh -server=postgresql -host=hostname -database=db_name -user=username -password=password_name -infolevel=minimum -command=schema -outputformat=htmlx -loglevel=CONFIG > schemaGraph.html

Comment: Please create an issue on GitHub - https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler

Answer (score 0):

Please try `--output-format` and see if it works.

Comment: still same issue. I am not receiving an output.